# Firestore : Query all collections orderBy and startsWith last 1 result

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query Firestore :

Collection "Users"

orderBy a column "User_Slug"

matches searchQuery e.g. "kanak" and

get last 1 result.

So, that if I have 
Total 3 documents in "Users"

- kanak-01
- kanak-02
- kanak-03

**Result must be kanak-03**

```
.orderBy("User_Slug", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
.startAt(queryText)
.get()
```

But, it is returning me all documents in Users whose slug matching starts with kanak and rest -

- kanak-01
- kanak-02
- kanak-03
- peter
- roman
- roman-02
- thomas
- victor

Comment: use `.limit(1)` in your query

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I have tried limit - it gives me result -- kanak-01. But I need kanak-03.

Comment: I think because your using ascending but you need descending

Comment: No, DESC doesn't works because it sorts the documents with empty results first.

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("User-Info");
usersRef.orderBy("User_Slug", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    .startAt(queryText)
    .endAt(queryText + "\uf8ff")
    .limit(1)
    .get();
```

Comment: in `.limit()` shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: @KanakSony Please add your database structure as a screenshot please.

Comment: This query should 100% work, I personality test it. Does it work also in your case?

Comment: Yeah, I saw your previous similar posts but in my case, it's not working. I am not expert in Firestore. Please check database structure -- https://ibb.co/nCJ9Mkr

Comment: It isn't working because you **don't** have a collection of `Users`, you collection is called `.collection("User-Info")`. See my updated answer and tell me if it work now.

Comment: :) that I have already corrected my side - else how I am getting results. An when I say not working - its not listing kanak-03 but its listing kanak-01. that's the problem

Comment: So are you getting now the results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198518/discussion-between-kanak-sony-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: @KanakSony could you tell what the problem was?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Check the chat discussion.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks. Didn't know I can join it.